# JavaFX: application Launch Must not be called more than once

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX and I was just typing some code...but whenever I try to run the application the second time I get an error stating: application launch must not be called more than once:

My first code was:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.*;

public class App extends Application{
    public void start (Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("Chess");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Application.launch (args);
    }
}
```

then after doing some search I changed it to:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.*;

public class App extends Application{
    public void start (Stage primaryStage){
        Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Chess");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Application.launch (args);
    }
}
```

But it still shows the same error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once

Comment: send your error msg.

Comment: How are you running this? Are you calling the `main(...)` method from somewhere else, or just running it in one of the regular ways?

Comment: I just call the main method...it's part of the class

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  I copied it to a file called `App.java`, compiled it with `javac App.java`, and then ran it with `java App`, and then closed it, and then ran it again with `java App`.  I did this with Java8u31 on Windows64.  I think there are some important details missing from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are adding

> Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
>   it is by default true, you don't need to call main method, just compile and run your application.

Comment: It has been a while since I visited the question, but I am pretty sure I just tested different function calls. I forgot to close the question, and I got it to work.